# How to find time difference between 2 log data in python and adding in tkinter treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, time, treeview

[image: on clicling submit button data gets added to tree with current time]

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Button, Label, Entry, ttk, StringVar, messagebox
import datetime

# Main Window
class WINDOW(Tk):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Tk.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master

        frame1 = Frame1(self)
        frame1.grid(row=0,column=0)

class Frame1(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master,height=master.winfo_screenheight(),
                       width=master.winfo_screenwidth())
        self.master = master

        var = StringVar()
        label = Label(self, text="DATA", font=('calibre', 10, 'bold'))
        entry = Entry(self, textvariable=var,width=10, font=('calibre', 10, 'normal'))
        label.grid(row=0, column=1)
        entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

        # Log data sheet
        NewTree = ttk.Treeview(self, height=23, columns=("Time","Time Diff", "DATA"))
        NewTree['show'] = 'headings'
        NewTree['columns'] = ("Time","Time Diff", "DATA")

        NewTree.column("Time", width=180)
        NewTree.column("Time Diff", width=150)
        NewTree.column("DATA", width=150)

        NewTree.heading("Time",text='TIME')
        NewTree.heading("Time Diff",text='TimeDIfference')
        NewTree.heading("DATA",text='DATA')


        NewTree.grid(row=5, columnspan=4)

        def insert_data():
            if entry.get()=='':
                messagebox.showerror("","Please insert data")
            else:
                NewTree.insert('', 'end',values=(datetime.datetime.now(),"",entry.get()))
                entry.delete(0, 'end')


        submit_button = Button(self, text="SUBMIT", command=insert_data)
        submit_button.grid(row=3, column=4)

root = WINDOW(None)
root.geometry(f'{root.winfo_screenwidth()}x{root.winfo_screenheight()}')
root.title("ADD DATA")
root.mainloop()
```

> Please refer the image:
> there is time difference between submitting the 11 and 12, 12 and 24 and so on.
> i need to calculate that time and want to add in time difference column.
>
> > it is like how much time it takes to add next data

Comment: What is receiving time? What is your definition of time difference? Usually time difference is the difference of initial time and a given time, what is initial time in this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure with what you are comparing the value, but my guess is the previous time.

you can use [`relativedelta`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) to get the time difference.

In the beginning, assign both `currenttime = previoustime = datetime.datetime.now()`. Then when ever the user calls `update` again assign `currenttime=datetime.datetime.now()` find the time difference, display the data in the treeview and then update `previoustime=currenttime`

Here is an example.

```py
from tkinter import ttk,Tk
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def diff(t_a, t_b):
    t_diff = relativedelta(t_b, t_a) 
    return '  {h}h {m}m {s}s {ms}ms'.format(h=abs(t_diff.hours), m=abs(t_diff.minutes), s=abs(t_diff.seconds), ms=abs(round(t_diff.microseconds*0.001, 2)))

def update():
    global currenttime, previoustime, timediff

    currenttime= datetime.datetime.now()
    timediff = diff(currenttime, previoustime)
    
    curr = tree.insert('','end',values=(currenttime,timediff))
    previoustime = currenttime
    tree.selection_set(curr)
    tree.see(curr)
    
root = Tk()
tree = ttk.Treeview(root, height = 20, columns = 2)
tree['show']='headings'
tree['columns'] = ('one','two')
tree.column('one', width = 250)
tree.column('two', width = 250)
tree.heading('one', text = 'TIME')
tree.heading('two', text = 'TIME Difference')
tree.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

currenttime= datetime.datetime.now()
previoustime= currenttime

timeBtn = ttk.Button(root, text='Update', command=update)
timeBtn.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.geometry("500x500")
root.mainloop()
```

Update after OP's request:

```
class Frame1(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        ...
        NewTree.grid(row=5, columnspan=4)
        
        self.currenttime = None
        self.previoustime = None
        self.timediff = None


        def diff(t_a, t_b):
            t_diff = relativedelta(t_b, t_a) 
            return '  {h}h {m}m {s}s {ms}ms'.format(h=abs(t_diff.hours), m=abs(t_diff.minutes), s=abs(t_diff.seconds), ms=abs(round(t_diff.microseconds*0.001, 2)))

        def update_time():
        
            if entry.get()=='':
                messagebox.showerror("","Please insert data")
         
            else:

                self.currenttime= datetime.datetime.now()

                if self.previoustime is None:
                    self.previoustime = self.currenttime
                
                self.timediff = diff(self.currenttime, self.previoustime)
                
                curr = NewTree.insert('','end',values=(datetime.datetime.now(), self.timediff ,entry.get()))
                self.previoustime = self.currenttime
                NewTree.selection_set(curr)
                NewTree.see(curr)
         
        submit_button = Button(self, text="SUBMIT", command=update_time) 
         ...
```

Comment: what is return statement in diff function. i didnt understand

Comment: @namratapatted What did you not understand is it the [formatting](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp)?

Comment: value of ms and im getting error while importing "from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta"

Comment: @namratapatted Can you tell me the full traceback? Also, `t_diff.microseconds` returns microseconds so to convert to milliseconds multiply by 0.001

Comment: i have altered my question which is bit clear now. please Help

Comment: @namratapatted pls elaborate your question. Are you trying to find the time difference between the two entries?

Comment: yes. exactly. im finding time difference between two entries

Comment: thank yo so much for your help @JacksonPro

Comment: can i just use time???? means hours:minute:seconds..... when i tried  with strftime to use only time , i got error like this :raise TypeError("relativedelta only diffs datetime/date")..help me out

Comment: @namratapatted  `strftime` returns a string. your error says that you are trying to pass a datetime instance and string instance to relativedelta. Here refer the  [source code](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/dateutil/relativedelta.html#relativedelta) for better understanding